# After updating the patches, 'displayDialogAsync' started giving the error - Unable to get property displayDialogAsync of undefined or null reference

Tags: office-js

One of my user got this error before and it got resolved by updating with office 2016 patch. He is started seeing this error again after updating his office 2016 with recent updates. What could be the reason for this error?

I confirm that office.js is loaded and can able to read excel data from Office.initialize block.

The supported excel API version on his machine is 1.10.
His office version is [Office version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yp6x.jpg).

Comment: According to this page that version should be supported. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/dialog-api-requirement-sets. This might be a bug. I suggest you raise an issue on the office-js repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=

Comment: Thanks Rick. I have posted in GitHub too. The issue was fixed after installing the office patch 'osfclient-x-none'. But, I am still worried how it can show the error again when it was working before.